# Using calculated property in EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have this Entity:

```
 public class MyDTO
    {
        int id;
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        DateTime createdOn;
        public DateTime CreatedOn
        {
            get { return createdOn; }
            set { createdOn = value; }
        }

        DateTime modifiedOn;
        public DateTime ModifiedOn
        {
            get { return modifiedOn; }
            set { modifiedOn = value; }
        }

        int duration;
        public int Duration
        {
            get { return ((TimeSpan)(ModifiedOn - CreatedOn)).Days; }
            protected set { }
        }
}
```

that `Duration` is calculated property, and also this mapping file:

```
internal partial class MyDTO_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyDTO>
{
    public MyDTO_Mapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        this.ToTable("MyDTO");
        this.Property(t => t.Id);
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedOn).HasColumnName("CreatedOn");
        this.Property(t => t.ModifiedOn).HasColumnName("ModifiedOn");
        this.Ignore(t => t.Duration);
    }
}
```

but when I want to make a query on this entity (I used `Duration` in my where clause), I get this error:

> The specified type member 'Duration' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Try to materialize (for example call `ToList()`) before filterting by that property.

Comment: @Giedrius is exactly right, you should write this into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LINQ query is translated into an SQL query and executed on the SQL server. The server has no knowledge of your calculated property, it will not translate a call to `Duration` into `((TimeSpan)(ModifiedOn - CreatedOn)).Days`. Thus, to access the value of `Duration` you need to get the objects out of the database first, and query on them afterwards.

As suggested, a call to `ToList()` or `ToArray()` will materialize (get from the database) your results.

If your filter on duration is important for performance (eg. it filters out many records), it might be smart to write a where clause copying the duration property's calculation, something like (untested):

```
from d in Context.MyDTOs where (d.ModifiedOn - d.CreatedOn).Days > 10 select d
```

Comment: "it might be smart to write a where clause copying the duration
 property's calculation."

could you please explain more?